# axios get from s3 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: amazon-s3, axios, cors

I want to get an image from AWS S3 but I receive **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'** even if I configured it both on request and on S3 config.

This is the request which fails:

```
await axios.get(property.thumbnail, { headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }, responseType: "blob" })
```

This is the S3 CORS configuration:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ]
    }
]
```

I attach also the bucket policy in case they could be helpful:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicListGet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname_censored>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname_censored>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the error:
[image: request error]

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` doesn't belong in a request.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of tests, I found out the problem was browser chaching prevents to send the **Origin** header to the server.

I solved by happending **headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-cache" }** to the axios GET request...

Comment: This was happening for me. The cache was set. I did a hard refresh and the set Origin was used